# Why would Activity Monitor and iotop give completely different output re: Disk Activity?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, process

I am trying to "rebuild" via DiskWarrior an external RAID0 startup drive… and it is "semi-stuck" on step 6..  but I have read that I should let it finish..  The strange thing is.. is that Activity monitor is showing constant R/W activity to "some drive" at 50+mB/s, yet when I check with `iotop` it shows virtually 0 disk activity.  What gives?

[image: disks going nuts, but hear no grinding]
[image: 100%cpu]
[image: iotop says no]

Comment: Is it possible that your particular action circumvents what is monitored by iotop/dtrace? Rebuilding a RAID 0 doesn't seem like an everyday event. Maybe the actual work happens via the kernel and is therefore excluded somehow?